# array_combine() merge common items

Tags: php, arrays

I want each item as a `key=>value` and do not want to merge/combine common item using `array_combine()`.

I want to combine foreach return value in `key=>value` and here is the result

```
foreach ($users_in_groups as $get_uid)
{
    $uid[] = $get_uid->user_id;
    $gnm[] = $get_uid->name;
}
```

Result for `$uid`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 1
)
```

Result for `$gnm`

```
Array
(
    [0] => member
    [1] => member
    [2] => system_admin
    [3] => admin
    [4] => TRA
    [5] => member
)
```

Combining as `key=>value`

```
array_combine($uid, $gnm);
```

Which is giving below result

```
Array
(
    [2] => member
    [3] => member
    [1] => member
)
```

Which is not what I want.

I want as below

```
Array
(
    [2] => member
    [3] => member
    [1] => system_admin
    [1] => admin
    [1] => TRA
    [1] => member
)
```

Please notice the userid as key and not combining like the current result.

Comment: What does your current attempt at this look like?

Comment: The output you're trying to get has identical keys. PHP doesn't permit identical keys so this won't work in the form you're asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, each array key must be a unique. This is not a valid PHP array because it has multiple keys that are the same (multiple instances of `1` as the key):

```
Array
(
    [2] => member
    [3] => member
    [1] => system_admin
    [1] => admin
    [1] => TRA
    [1] => member
)
```

You can test this by manually creating an array with multiple keys that are the same:

```
$c = array(
    1 => 'a',
    3 => 'b',
    3 => 'c',
);
print_r($c);
```

In PHP 5.5, this results in:

```
Array
(
    [1] => a
    [3] => c
)
```

What you should aim for is maybe (depending on your needs) an array like this:

```
array(
    2 => array('member'),
    3 => array('member'),
    1 => array('system_admin', 'admin', 'TRA', 'member'),
);
```

If that is what you need, you can use the following:

```
$uid = array(2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1);
$gnm = array('member', 'member', 'system_admin', 'admin', 'TRA', 'member');
$result = array();
foreach($uid as $k => $u) {
    if (!isset($result[$u])) {
        $result[$u] = array();
    }
    $result[$u][] = $gnm[$k];
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: This is right. And because that last member is mapped to the key `1`, that's why you get 3 results.

Comment: Thank you very much. I never thought about nested array.